# Linux shell commands not found even though their paths are listed in the PATH variable

Tags: linux, shell, google-app-engine, terminal, command-line-interface

The google app engine cli commands cannot be found in the python sdk. I've already checked the google_appengine file. The shell commands are there, and I already added the app engine file path to the PATH variable. I echo the PATH variable and the directory to the app_engine file shows up, but still shows not found when I try to use a command that's inside the file. If I reference the command directly by using its whole path, the command works, but otherwise it won't. Is there anything else that needs to be done to reference a command in shell?

Comment: Do you `export` your PATH?

Comment: I exported it in the .bashrc fle, and then when that didn't work I also tried just typing the value of the PATH variable without the export statement in the .bashrc file - as I saw other tutorials do the same

Comment: Take a look at [this answer](http://askubuntu.com/questions/98433/run-a-script-on-login-using-bash-login).

Answer (score 0):

More error info please,

> If I reference the command directly by using its whole path, the command works

I think your python path maybe wrong, *Python 2.6 is not supported.*

so are you have mulit-version python?

Comment: When I said "shell commands cannot be found" in the title, it literally meant the error was that the command could not be found, or word for word, `dev_appserver.py: command not found`

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your contributions everyone. It turns out the path I was using was wrong. Instead of `/home/Programs/Apps/google_appengine` it should have been `/home/Programs/google_appengine`. I guess the shell doesn't check to see if the path you add to the PATH variable actually exists. Who knew? Not me

Until I run into another problem stack overflow--which may be soon
See ya